# Different plugins activated online and offline

Tags: plugins, activation, deactivation

I develop / add to / etc. my site offline, then transfer the updated database (in toto) to the live site. Some of the plugins I need / use offline, I don't need online, and vice versa.

Is there a way to have one set of plugins active if the database is 'online' and a different set for 'offline'? Or do I just need to accept that whenever I upload a new version of the database I need to activate / deactivate as appropriate?

Comment: There is nothing built in that would do this, and in my opinion, building something to do it would not be worth the time.

Comment: I agree with s_ha_dum, this is something that you have to do manually everytime.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum / Pieter. Was just being a bit lazy - it isn't a problem most of the time ... the plugins I don't use online I don't have installed there and WordPress automatically deactivates them. It was just one, that I need to use online, but causes a conflict when working offline on "Desktopserver" (W3 Total Cache) so I can't have it active there. I'll mark your answer as 'accepted' as soon as I work out how :-) [Seem to recall there may be a 'minimum time' factor before I can.]